# I want to implement database to my java web app

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc, database-schema

I am newbie with database. I have knowledge of java. I am using play framework(java not scala) to develop a web app.

Now for storing informationof users I need to setup a database. As I have no experience with any type of database. I searched and short listed 3.

1. Mysql
2. Mongodb
3. Cassandra

I have seen a lot of examples of implement this database in java project using jdbc. Using there query language. Example: SQL in java.

I don't know any query language. Also I don't want to learn query language and delay the project

After going through the database vendors site. They provide drivers. So my questions are:

1. Can I use mysql without learning sql. Using driver. Connecting to database to do crud etc without creating schema. With only java. I know other listed database are schema free. So can I do the query in those database also with only java syntax.
2. When I searched I came to know about hibernate and spring data. Can I connect to database using this framework without the use of query language of those databases.
3. I wanna know a practical way to connect with those listed database without knowing there query languages.

Comment: Unfortunately programming involves a lot of learning, so you're going to have to learn something. I'd recommend SQL since it's the most widespread and definitely something worth knowing. It's not very hard either, at least for simple things.

Comment: You want to do programming without learning any programming? This looks like a troll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think what you're asking is possible.  And if it is possible then I certainly wouldn't recommend it.

Hibernate will shelter you somewhat from having to do basic SQL commands for lookups and updates, however it's not a replacement, you will often have to fall back to HQL and possibly SQL.  You really need to understand more about this before you start to use databases, otherwise you'll end up in a mess.

As for it delaying your project, it's better to delay the project than to continue in the dark.  After all, time spent learning is never time wasted!

Comment: i think its possible. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver-async/getting-started/quick-tour/ and http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/